# How to run a docker container at startup under nixos

Tags: docker, nixos

I would like to run a pre-built docker container under NixOS.
I would like to do this in a Nix-ish way:

1. Install the container from docker hub itself via a nix expression, which is thus reproducible.  The docker is currently listed as 'latest', I'm hoping that there is some way to go from that to a version id.
2. Run the container from startup, by embedding an expression (indirectly) in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, presumably via a `systemd` service, thus configuring this declaratively.

I have found a few pages about *building* docker containers from within nix, although I can't even get example number 4 [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/docker/examples.nix) working.  But I haven't found any examples of running containers via the system declaration.

I would really appreciate some help or pointers (or examples!) here, I'm thrashing around a bit trying to make stuff work.  I have only a passing familiarity with docker.

Comment: Here's a relevant issue: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/37553

Comment: Perhaps you could ask copumpkin on IRC what the problems with his declarative containers module were

Comment: According to that it's an experimental feature?

Answer (score 4):

Since NixOS 20.09 there is the [`virtualisation.oci-containers`](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/options.html#opt-virtualisation.oci-containers.containers) option that lets you define arbitrary [OCI-compliant](https://opencontainers.org/release-notices/v1-0-0/) containers to be mapped into systemd units.

There used to be [`config.docker-containers`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/55179) in NixOS 20.03 as well, but this option has been deprecated in favour of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a 'nix-ish' way but if you just pull the docker image (you can pull a specific version by specifying a tag or a sha256 of the image).

And then either use the docker's daemon functionality to start it up automatically at boot (`--restart` flag), or you could write a systemd unit file (this unit file might have some integration potential with nixos) to start it for you.

Not a very conclusive answer - but seeing no other answers, hopefully this helps!